# imagemagick and jp2 problems

Tags: imagemagick, centos7, rhel7

I compiled and created and rpm for the latest ImageMagick with jp2 support

```
convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-07-30 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fftw fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg ltdl lzma pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

So as you can see jp2 is in the delegates. 
yet we keep getting this error :

```
convert: unable to load module `/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1//modules-Q16HDRI/coders/jp2.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1282.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JP2' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined `/tmp/131C6D7C-165E-11E4-A6EB-3950957D6753.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.
```

the file is where it should be.

PS: this is on RHEL7

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the last post in this thread is relevant to your situation... http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24983

Comment: What flags did you use with `./configure`? I'm guessing IM was told to load from `/usr/lib`, but the library is really setting in `/usr/lib64` (or something else as simple as that).

Comment: @emcconville 
this was my configure command
`./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-hdri --with-modules --with-perl --disable-static`. 

I will try to recompile explicitly mentioning /usr/lib64.

Comment: Later versions of ImageMagick use OpenJpeg2000 v2.1.0 or higher to process JP2 images and no longer Jasper. So install the OpenJpeg delegate library.